# Producing a two-way ANOVA plot with error bars from a data.frame

Tags: r, plot, anova, errorbar

I have the following data.frame:

```
Height Color Sales    
short  blue    24    
short  blue    25    
short  blue    30    
short  blue    28    
short  blue    25    
short   red    31    
short   red    28    
short   red    33    
short   red    35    
short   red    32    
short black    35    
short black    32    
short black    31    
short black    38    
short black    35    
tall  blue    31    
tall  blue    32    
tall  blue    33    
tall  blue    36    
tall  blue    32    
tall   red    36    
tall   red    32    
tall   red    33    
tall   red    41    
tall   red    34    
tall black    41    
tall black    36    
tall black    34    
tall black    32    
tall black    39
```

From this, I want to produce a figure like the one shown below:

[image: Desired plot (but without error bars)]

I would like to know how to generate the plot with error bars in two ways: (a) with ggplot2; and (b) without it.

(Unfortunately, I am not allowed to install additional packages in computers on campus, but ggplot2 has been installed. I would like to show my students how to generate the plot on campus.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus I am afraid that I know so little about R that I am basically clueless as to how to deal with the data.frame to produce the desired plot.

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(dat, aes(x = Color, y = Sales, linetype = Height, group = Height)) + stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', geom = 'line')`

Comment: Adding to that: [this online introductory text](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) might help you to get started.

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus thank you for your prompt reply.  I am wondering if you know how to add error bars to the plot.  I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: `+ stat_summary(fun = "mean_cl_normal")`

Comment: @Axeman thank you for your help.  I tried the line and got the error message: Error: Unknown parameters: fun  I tried "fun.y" (imitating what I found in the code by Procrastinatus Maximus), but it did not work.  I am sorry that I know so little about R.

Comment: Sorry, `+ stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal")` should work. Add it to Procrastinus' code.

Comment: @Axeman It worked! (I also needed to install "Hmisc").  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus thank you for the reference; it is actually very helpful.